How to update to Fedora 40 with GPG errors
When I attempt a dnf upgrade I get this as result:
error: Verifying a signature using certificate 2C6106201985B60E6C7AC87323F3D4EA75716059 (GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>):
  1. Certificate 23F3D4EA75716059 invalid: certificate is not alive
      because: The primary key is not live
      because: Expired on 2024-09-06T11:17:19Z
  2. Key 23F3D4EA75716059 invalid: key is not alive
      because: The primary key is not live
      because: Expired on 2024-09-06T11:17:19Z
packages for the GitHub CLI                                                                                                 20 kB/s | 4.7 kB     00:00    
GPG key at https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x23F3D4EA75716059 (0x75716059) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "packages for the GitHub CLI" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: gh-2.58.0-1.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x23F3D4EA75716059
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED

--nogpgcheckdoes not help.
How do I successfully update to Fedora 40?

Try to disable gpg check in
/etc/dnf/dnf.conf

change
gpgcheck=True

to
gpgcheck=False

That way I was able to update Fedora server that was offline for a long time

In this case I had to uninstall the github package first as it seems to be broken.
sudo dnf uninstall gh

after that I could upgrade to F40 via the normal means.
